# Gluetun with Purevpn Docker Compose not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run Firefox behind Gluetun with PureVPN. But anytime I access the page just get site cannot be reached. I have the ports forwarded with PureVPN and have tried using `FIREWALL=off` but no luck.

Any ideas?

Should be able to access the IP and the port running on 3000

I have tried multiple different things, turning firewall off.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  gluetun:
    image: qmcgaw/gluetun:latest
    container_name: gluetun
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    ports:
      - 8888:8888/tcp # HTTP proxy
      - 8388:8388/tcp # Shadowsocks
      - 8388:8388/udp # Shadowsocks
      - 8001:8000/tcp # Built-in HTTP control server
      - 3000:3000 # Firefox
      - 32400:32400/tcp # Plex
    volumes:
      - /volume1/docker/delugevpn/gluetun:/gluetun
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/London
      - VPN_SERVICE_PROVIDER=purevpn
      - OPENVPN_PROTOCOL=tcp
      - OPENVPN_USER=purevpn
      - OPENVPN_PASSWORD=pass
      - SERVER_COUNTRIES=Germany
      - SERVER_HOSTNAMES=af2-auto-tcp.ptoserver.com
  firefox:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/firefox:latest
    container_name: firefox
    environment:
       - PUID=1000
       - PGID=1000
       - TZ=Europe/London
    volumes:
       - /volume1/docker/firefox:/config
    shm_size: '1gb'
    network_mode: 'service:gluetun'
    depends_on:
      - gluetun
```